# Email Error - couriertls: read: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Tags: email, ssl, plesk

I am running Plesk v12.5.30_build1205150826.19 os_Ubuntu 12.04 and getting the following errors when try to send emails.

```
Sep 20 18:35:59 lvps109-104-93-126 postfix/smtpd[14585]: connect from unknown[194.0.158.9]

Sep 20 18:35:59 lvps109-104-93-126 courier-pop3s: couriertls: read: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Sep 20 18:36:01 lvps109-104-93-126 last message repeated 10 times

Sep 20 18:36:01 lvps109-104-93-126 postfix/smtpd[27545]: connect from unknown[194.0.158.9]

Sep 20 18:36:01 lvps109-104-93-126 courier-pop3s: couriertls: read: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Sep 20 18:36:02 lvps109-104-93-126 last message repeated 9 times
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Try use instructions from https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213958525-Courier-IMAPs-issue-after-system-upgrade-SSL-routines-SSL3-GET-RECORD-wrong-version-number